# How does this compile if std::pow is not allowed to be constexpr for compatibility with setting things like errno?

Tags: c++, arrays, constexpr, compile-time

The following C++ snippet runs and compiles fine on, for example, the below platform (not sure which compiler is used under the hood). But aren't array sizes required to be known at compile time?

https://onlinegdb.com/H1qovLHGV

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cmath>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
    int foo[(int) std::pow(3, 5)];
    foo[2] = 0;
    cout<<"Hello World " << foo[2] << endl;

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Yes, for array allocated on stack the size has to be a compile time constant, in standard C++. Some compilers aloow Variable Length Array as extension, but that's not a portable solution. onlinegdb uses g++ (see it's [FAQ](https://www.onlinegdb.com/faq)), which does allow that.

Comment: Note that you can force standard compliancy: https://wandbox.org/permlink/s2VWfrPLBnW4YIuH vs. https://wandbox.org/permlink/RWoOtxd6tpUCh3wG

Comment: makes sense - i can't seem to get it to error on godbolt where it supposedly takes flags (-fno-builtin) and also trying under clang: https://godbolt.org/z/FnSk-w but your example with wandbox worked, was it pedantic-errors that did the trick?

Comment: @user4581301 edited the question from 2 to 3 to avoid that easy unrelated suggestion :)

Comment: @PalaceChan add `-pedantic` to the command line to get a standard compliance warning.

Comment: @PalaceChan Yes. Saw that and laughed.

Comment: @PalaceChan Yes, `-pedantic` or specifically [`-Wvla-extension`](https://godbolt.org/z/t_SPfK) for this case.